# SQL Server scheduled backup to Azure Table bacpac

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server

I moved my database from Azure SQL to Windows Server 2008 R2 + SQL Server 2012 Web edition virtual machine on Windows Azure.

The Azure SQL provided automated backup to Azure Table as bacpac file. It was good feature for me.

Similarly, I'd like to make scheduled backup as bacpac file to Windows Azure Storage with my VM. is there any tutorial, or how can I do?

I checked [SQL Backup And FTP](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/) tool, but it is not enough for me (Azure Table push is not supported).